# Anaconda "Problem reading non-conda package record"

Tags: python, anaconda

I find myself routinely making backups of Anaconda environments whenever I update them, in case I need to do a rollback. Recently, whenever running the **conda export --file {file}** command, I've been getting the following warning:

WARNING conda.core.prefix_data:_load_site_packages(291): Problem reading non-conda package record at Lib/site-packages/webencodings-0.5.1-py3.7.egg-info/PKG-INFO. Please verify that you still need this, and if so, that this is still installed correctly. Reinstalling this package may help.

Now I know this is just a warning, and usually whatever command I'm giving anaconda will just finish. However, warnings always trigger both my anxiety and my curiosity, so I set out to find a cause.

A Google search with the exact wording resulted in absolutely nothing, so I set out to reinstall the named package "webencodings", which I'm pretty sure is only installed as a dependency for another package (though I can't really figure out which one at this point). Reinstalling goes off without a hitch, but as soon as I try to export the environment, I get the warning message again.

I've looked at the mentioned PKG-INFO file, and compared it to that of NumPy, but found nothing that indicates one of them is a 'conda package' and the other a 'non-conda package'.

Has anyone dealt with this problem before? Is there any sensible way to fix it? Should I open a bug report at Anaconda?

If there's more information needed, I'd happily include it, but I'd rather hold off sending my entire Anaconda debug overview or environment specs on SO for now (it's a lot of text...)